# New parameter causing Web API action to return 404

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Getting 404 after adding a new parameter `itemGroup` to the already working Web API 2 action. Not able to figure out what I did wrong.

**Controller**

```
[RoutePrefix("v2/calendar")]
public class CalendarController : ApiController
```

**Action**

```
[Route("list/{typeId:int}/{count:int}/{itemGroup:alpha?}/{startDate:DateTime?}")]
public List<CalendarItem> Calendar(int typeId, int count, string itemGroup = null, DateTime? startDate = null)
{
}
```

**Client Call**
`/v2/public/calendar/list?typeId=7&count=31&itemGroup=abc&startDate=10-20-2018`

Comment: There are mulitple questions about this, see: https://www.google.com/search?q=web+api+multiple+optional+parameters+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optional Parameters in Web Api Attribute Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778640/optional-parameters-in-web-api-attribute-routing)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! "You really should use query strings for optional parameters and path parameters if they are required." https://stackoverflow.com/a/42115291/1541224